# Vertical scrollbars with window.open

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I am opening a popop windows with window.open. I want the scrollbars to show up if needed. However in safari, the scrollbars are not showing up unless I set, scrollbars=1,

However that makes even horizontal scrollbars show up. Is there a way to specify,

"Show only horizontal scrollbars, if needed" to popop window.

(Possibly via some combinations of options to window.open, and overflow, css property.)

Comment: `scrollbars=1` is exactly what you need (though you've mistyped it in your question). Perhaps there is something in the popup page that is wider than you think.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've been messing with this a little and I settled on this solution until I find a better one:

```
window.open('http://yoursite.com','mypopup',
  'status=1,width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1');
```

Then in the CSS of yoursite.com, put this:

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

In some browsers, a vertical scrollbar may show even if the content fits in the window. But the horizontal scroll bar should not show.

Comment: scrollbars will not be present *by default* with `window.open()` so you have to add the option to show them if you want them

Comment: What's the `status=1` for?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot I found this suitable

```
window.open("http://www.classi5.blogspot.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400"
```